# Como refatorar esse codigo que manipula datas em PHP?

Tags: php, refatoração

Tenho um código onde mostra o tempo em que a notificação foi criada, e para isto utilizo uma data que vem do Banco de dados no formato (Y-m-d H:i:s) e a data atual no mesmo formato.

Então tem a gambiarra abaixo que consegui chegar para resolver este problema, porém sei muito bem que isto está totalmente errado de se fazer.. é funcional, mas não é um código bom... Tem alguma outra forma para resolver isto? sla tipo um switch ou algo do tipo. Me ajudem, sou novo na linguagem e procuro sempre está estudando boas práticas.. kkk

**Código:**

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo'); // Determina o fuso da região
$now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); //determina a data atual neste formato


$start_date = new DateTime($data_do_banco); //Data do Banco está no formato (Y-m-d H:i:s)
$since_start = $start_date->diff(new DateTime($now));

if ($since_start->y != '0') {
    if ($since_start->y == '1') {
        echo $since_start->y.' ano';
    }else {
        echo $since_start->y.' anos';
    }
}else{
    if ($since_start->m != '0') {
        if ($since_start->m == '1') {
            echo $since_start->m.' mês';
        }else {
            echo $since_start->m.' meses';
        }
    }else {
        if ($since_start->d != 0) {
            if ($since_start->d == '1') {
                echo $since_start->d.' dia';
            }else {
                echo $since_start->d.' dias';
            }
        }else{
            if ($since_start->h != 0) {
                if ($since_start->h == '1') {
                    echo $since_start->h.' h';
                }else {
                    echo $since_start->h.' hs';
                }
            }else{
                if ($since_start->i != 0) {
                    echo $since_start->i.' min';
                }else {
                    if ($since_start->s != 0) {
                        echo $since_start->s.' seg';
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Só um detalhe, para obter a data atual vc não precisa dessa variável `$now`, basta fazer `new DateTime()`

Comment: Importante sempre fornecer um [mcve] da tentativa de solução e descrição clara da parte com dúvida no lugar do código original. Para entender que tipo de pergunta serve para o site e, consequentemente, evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) e o [Guia de sobrevivência (resumido) do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/70) - a tag "refatoração" também foi acrescentada indevidamente depois, nela mesmo há a instrução de que não é para pedidos de refatoração.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer um loop, e usar `$since_start->{$x}`, sendo que o `$x` muda para cada iteração:

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo'); // Determina o fuso da região
$now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); //determina a data atual neste formato


$start_date = new DateTime($data_do_banco); //Data do Banco está no formato (Y-m-d H:i:s)
$since_start = $start_date->diff(new DateTime($now));


$m = ["y" => ["ano", "anos"], "m" => ["mês", "meses"], "d" => ["dia", "dias"], "h" => ["hora", "horas"], "i" => ["minuto", "minutos"], "s" => ["segundo", "segundos"]];


foreach($m as $k => $v) {
    if (($t = $since_start->{$k}) > 0) {
        echo $t . " " . ($t == 1 ? $v[0] : $v[1]);
        break;
    }
}
```

O `$t = $since_start->{$k}` pegará a informação baseada no chave do "array", no caso será `y` (e depois `m` (...)). Para cada um, compara se for maior ou igual à `1` para retornar o `ano` ou `anos` (que é o index 0 e 1 do array).

Comment: Algum motivo especifico para os votos negativos, `-2`?

Comment: Down votes aqui rola solto. Ou tem um bot atribui down vote ou então alguém que faz isso por prazer mesmo. Caso eu esteja falando besteira, poderiam ao menos falar o motivo do -

Comment: @MarcosXavier eu já deixei de ligar pra downvote, mas nesse caso foram 2, assim que postei (um foi revertido), então achei que teria algo muito errado com o código. kkk. Até porque nem uso mais PHP, então achei que teria uma maneira melhor ou sei lá, essa solução estaria muito obsoleta..

Comment: O downvote tá exagerado aqui nessa parada. Postei e já venho dois em pouco tempo.

Comment: @raphael eu dei um +1 na sua resposta (embora acho que ela ainda continue com a duplicação de código). Mas, não sei o motivo do -2, a minha resposta também estava com -2. Parece que isso ocorre mais nas perguntas/respostas em PHP. A pergunta em si não é muito boa, mas não sei se deveria punir as respostas com votos negativos.

Comment: agradeço. Não dei a melhor das repostas, só tentei dar um caminho para o cara não aninhar tantos ifs e else um dentro do outro. Vou dar +1 na sua resposta ai também.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela sua resposta, a utilização dos arrays combinados com o foreach foi ótima. Por mais que todas as respostas tenham sido boas e funcionais está com toda certeza ficou bem mais clean.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar operador ternário para simplificar as verificações. Além disso, dá para encerrar a execução dentro de uma função usando *return*, assim evita um if/else aninhados (um dentro do outro).

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo'); // Determina o fuso da região

$start_date = new DateTime($data_do_banco); //Data do Banco está no formato (Y-m-d H:i:s)
$since_start = $start_date->diff(new DateTime);

function mostrarData($since_start){

    if($since_start->y > 0){
        $text = $since_start->y == '1' ?  'ano' : 'anos';
        echo  $since_start->y . $text;
        return; // finaliza a execução para não ter que colocar if e else um dentro do outro
    }

    // aqui você seguiria com o restante do código 
    // com cada verificação repetindo a mesma lógica para as outras partes da data além do ano
}

mostrarData($since_start);
```

OBS: O objeto DateTime sem parâmetros no construtor já cria um objeto com a data atual, logo não precisa passar explicitamente como você estava fazendo através da variável `$now`.

Answer (score -1):

Baseado no seu script fiz um outro script bem simples seguindo alguns conceitos de clean code (veja mais [aqui](https://br.phptherightway.com/)).

Repare que adicionei o método validarData e a minha idéia é tentar ajudar você mostrando que se a condição if já foi atendida e você não necessita de mais nenhuma validação/verificação  o [return](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.return.php) pode (talvez deve) ser utilizado. Caso não queira utilizar a idéia de colocar as verificações em uma [função](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/functions.user-defined.php), dá uma lida aqui [break](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.break.php). Você pode exibir o texto e encerrar o fluxo com **break**

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo'); // Determina o fuso da região
$now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); //determina a data atual neste formato

$start_date = new DateTime('2021-12-04 22:35:00'); //Data do Banco está no formato (Y-m-d H:i:s)
$since_start = $start_date->diff(new DateTime($now));


echo validarData($since_start) . PHP_EOL;

function validarData($since_start) {

    if ($since_start->y > 0)  {
        return $since_start->y > 1 ?  $since_start->y . ' anos' :  $since_start->y . ' ano';
    }
        
    if ($since_start->m > 0) {
        return  $since_start->m > 1 ? $since_start->m . ' meses' :  $since_start->m . ' mês';
    }

    if ($since_start->d > 0) {
        return $since_start->d > 1 ? $since_start->d . ' dias' : $since_start->d . ' dia';
    }
    
    if ($since_start->h > 0) {
        return $since_start->h > 1 ? $since_start->h . ' hs' : $since_start->h . ' h';
    }    

    if ($since_start->i > 0) {
        return  $since_start->i. ' min' ;
    }
    
    if ($since_start->s > 0) {
        return $since_start->s.' seg';
    }
}
```